# How do I find and remove unnecessary dependency in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dependencies, reference

I have a problem when I am building in Visual Studio 10. There is a circular dependency towards another project's exe-file (which I found using DebugView) that makes large parts of the solution rebuild everytime. This dependency is unnecessary and I have no idea why it is present.

My problem is that I cannot find where it is defined, and therefore cannot fix the problem. I have searched for the name of the exe-file in the .vcxproj but it is not present (and I have not find it anywhere in the projects properties in VS10's GUI either). I made a search for the name of the exe-fil in explorer in all the solution's files but could not find it making a dependency there either.

The dependency is probably hidden in a variable somewhere, but how can I find it?

(I have also looked through the External Dependency folder in the project, but there was only header and inl files there).

Best regards
Josef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Reference Assistant](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fc504cc6-5808-4da8-ae86-8d3f9ed81606) may help.

It is one of my favorite supplements to **ReSharper**.

Answer (score 0):

If you point [Structure101](http://www.structure101.com) at your assemblies, and specify the "assembly breakout" (as opposed to "namespace breakout"), and go to the structure tab, composition perspective, you will see a dependency diagram of your assemblies. If you click the "auto-partition" button (a magic wand icon), it will put a red box around the cyclically dependent assemblies, and indicate in red the minimum set of dependencies you need to remove in order to make the graph acyclic - usually you want to focus on the lighter dependencies, in your case it may have a count of just 1. The count of code-level references is shown next to each dependency arrow - if you select a dependency, you can see all the code-level references that cause the assembly-to-assembly dependency in the dependency breakout under the graph - this should indicate the culprit that is causing the bad dependency.

Comment: That seems like a good way to find what the project is dependent on. But what I need to know is where in the project this dependency is defined. I have a project A and B where A is dependent on B. But somewhere B is set to be dependent on the executable file created by A, which creates the cyclic dependency. I just can't find where in B's preferences I need to update, so that it's no longer dependent on the executable from A.

Comment: If the B to A dependency is being used (something in B calls something in A) then you need to refactor the code so it isn't being used first, then remove the project dependency from the project menu - see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx